# Ponteiros em C, erro ao invocar a função de realocação

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro

Tenho o código em C escrito abaixo, sempre que pretendo invocar a função da uma erro que diz:
--/home/samuel-o-cara/Documents/Estruturas de Dados e Algoritmo/Aula 13.04.16 AlocarMemoria/main.c|80|error: conflicting types for ‘alocarEspaco’|

```
pessoa* alocarEspaco(pessoa *p, int tam)
{
   pessoa* ptr = &p;
   ptr = (pessoa*) malloc(tam*sizeof(pessoa));
   return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> conflicting types for ‘alocarEspaco’

Tens um prototipo da funcao (definido antes, provavelmente num `#include`) com assinatura diferente da usada na definicao.

Answer (score 0):

Seu parâmetro já é um ponteiro, nesse caso, você não precisa do "&". Além disso, se a função vai retornar um ponteiro para o espaço alocado, você não precisa fornecer um ponteiro como parâmetro. Tenta da seguinte forma:

```
pessoa* alocarEspaco(int tam)
{
    pessoa *ptr = (pessoa*) malloc(tam*sizeof(pessoa));
    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na sua declaração:

```
pessoa* alocarEspaco(pessoa p, int tam)
```

Não é necessário `pessoa p` pois o método já irá alocar fazer a alocação da memória. E quando for usar tamanho para fazer contagem ou alocar memória, opte por usar `unsigned` na descrição, pois o `unsigned` faz com que todos os valores que coloque passem a ser positivos (É mais uma forma de organização). Assim deixando seu método da seguinte forma:

```
pessoa* alocarEspaco(unsigned int tam)
```

Para poder alocar memória em uma variável, ela precisa ser um ponteiro, e para isso, é necessário que coloque um `*` (asterisco) na declaração.

```
pessoa *ptr; // essa variável é um ponteiro por que tem um "*" na declaração
ptr = (pessoa *) malloc(sizeof(pessoa)*tam);
return ptr;
```

---

Agora, a variável que for receber o valor, deve ser um ponteiro também.

```
pessoa *var = alocarEspaco(10); // aloca 10 pessoas em var
```

E agora a parte que muita gente faz confusão.

> **Como pegar as posições do ponteiro?**

Quando o ponteiro tem **1** espaço se usa `->`. Ex:

```
pessoa *uma_pessoa = alocarEspaco(1);
uma_pessoa->idade = 10;
uma_pessoa->nome = "Fulano";
```

Mas claro que isso é para quando o ponteiro tem apenas **1** espaço. Quando possuir vários espaços se usa `.` (ponto). Ex:

```
pessoa *muitas_pessoas = alocarEspaco(10);
muitas_pessoas[0].nome = "Ciclano";
muitas_pessoas[1].nome = "Dertrano";
/*...*/
```

> **Porque isso?**

Porque quando pega uma posição usando `[n]`, você já está acessando o endereço de memória. Então se o seu ponteiro tiver uma posição pode usar o `->`, e se tiver arias posições, deve usar o `[n]` (número nos coxetes).

Comment: Valeu meus manos, investiguei mais um pouco e ja resolvi. So tinha que declarar a funcao nos prototipos